# UICollectionView gestures ignored when inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UITableView that contains cells, each one containing a UILabel, some buttons and a UICollectionView.

When a cell is tapped, the UITableViewDelegate's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is invoked. If tapped on a button, the button's action is invoked. However, if tapped on the UICollectionView, the UICollectionViewDelegate's didSelectItemAtIndexPath method is not invoked, the UITableViewDelegate's didSelectRowAtIndexPath is invoked instead.

I tried to fix it by adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UICollectionView but it's also being ignored.

Does anybody know of a way to keep both events working at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan

Comment: Could u share a screenshot of your tableview cell so I could create a small demo and try to fix your issue.

Comment: The question was too complex for a simple mistake made by me.

Answer (score -1):

My mistake. The User Interaction Enabled flag was set to NO for the UICollectionView.